# How can I loop over sheets in an Excel workbook and transpose the data in each sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a VBA macro that will transpose the data on every sheet in an Excel workbook (turn the columns into rows and rows into columns).

I've tried different versions of the following code, but PasteSpecial seems to cause problems when it's inside a loop.

```
Dim WS_Count As Integer
Dim i As Integer

WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

For i = 1 To WS_Count
    Worksheets(i).UsedRange.Copy
    Worksheets(i).Cells.ClearContents
    Worksheets(i).Range("A1").PasteSpecial Transpose = True
Next i
```

It gives me a run-time error '1004': PasteSpecial method of Range class failed.

Comment: How many rows/columns are involved?

Comment: Get your last row of used range, Paste the copied rows below the usedrange row at colomn A, delete row from row 1 to your saved Last Row (last row of previous used range)

Comment: @MathieuGuindon, I'm currently using this macro on sheets with around 10 rows and columns, but I need it to be flexible about the ranges involved.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that error because this line is pulling you out of Cut/Copy mode:

`Worksheets(i).Cells.ClearContents`

---

This transposes the `UsedRange` of every worksheet in the `ActiveWorkbook` and accommodates any number of columns or rows.

```
Sub TransposeIt()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim c As Long
    Dim r As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        With ws.UsedRange
            c = .Columns.Count
            r = .Rows.Count
            .Copy
        End With
        With ws
            .Cells(1, c + 1).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
            .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, c)).EntireColumn.Delete
        End With
    Next ws
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Since you ask, the DV was placed prior to your edits.  That version simply didn't work.  BTW the edited version still has issues. Consider what happens if UsedRange doesn't start at A1.  Also the OP is unclear on a few points: do they want to transpose formatting?   What if the transposed range contains Formulas?  What if other cells have formulas referring to the transposed range?

Comment: @chris neilsen It is pretty obvious what the OPs intent is, both in written context and via code.  While the specific cases you mention are noteworthy in a larger context, they are irrelevant to the OPs question.

Comment: The OP has clearly stumbled on the PasteSpecial part. How do _you_ know that other issues wouldn't become a factor after they solve that bit?  And answers on SO are as much for future readers as the OP.  If you don't want to address those issues in your answer  that's fine,  but at least mention there existence.

Comment: @chris neilsen I am a bit dense, I just came about to agreeing with your first comment because you were absolutely right about formulas and formats; I had not considered I was only bringing values.  But I'll draw the line at divination.  If other factors come into play then another question should be made.  Post updated to reflect the OP's methods more accurately.